# javafx and javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, javafx

I have generally been underwhelmed by JavaFX, but at least their [API documentation is a big improvement](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1/docs/api/) over javadoc which has not gone through any substantial improvement in a decade. Is it possible to use JavaFX technology to generate [more attractive javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1/docs/api/) for regular Java files?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of replacement javadoc doclets, some [here](http://doclet.com/) ( a bit out of date, but lots of interesting ideas).

Answer (score 0):

I mainly use

[Docjar](http://www.docjar.com/)

It allows displaying the source code of each method or the whole class/interface.

Comment: There's even an Eclipse plugin.