# Are there some good and modern alternatives to Javadoc?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

Let's face it: You don't need to be a designer to see that
default **Javadoc looks ugly**.

There are some resources on the web which offer re-styled Javadoc. But the default behaviour represents the product and should be as reasonably good-looking.

Another problem is the fact that the usability of Javadoc is not up-to-date compared to other similar resources.

Especially huge projects are hard to navigate using Firefox's quick search.

**Practical question:**
Are there any standalone (desktop) applications which are able to browse 
existing Javadoc in a more usable way than a browser would?
*I'm thinking about something like Mono's documentation browser.*

**Theoretical question:**
Does anyone know, if there some plans to evolve Javadoc, in a
somehow-standardized way?
**EDIT:** [A useful link to Sun' wiki on this topic](http://wikis.sun.com/display/Javadoc/Home).

Comment: I would be happy if javadoc would generate valid HTML 4.01 or XHTML pages.

Comment: What usabilitiy problems do you have?

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this? I think it is a reasonable question: +1

Comment: (X)HTML should not be the only way for Javadoc. The browser is a very limited tool for accessing a (local) knowledge base.

Comment: @basszero: Searching the JDK documentation with Firefox's quick search is not very usable ;) -- @Daniel: Some people seem to take it personal, when someone dislikes Javadoc.

Comment: People would downvote this because it's phrased arrogantly and aggressively.

Comment: I personally like Javadoc. It's clear, concise, and to the point. The MSDN site on the other hand...

Comment: @ivan_ivanovich_ivanoff - Please let that be your real name; I'm very envious

Comment: @Michael: ok, I'll remove "outdated" from the question's title  --  
@oxbow_lakes: it's nearly my real name ;)

Comment: I'd classify "Web 1.0" as a retronym - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retronym

Comment: @Alan M - thank you for the nice term "retronym", I like it!

Comment: I tried to re-phrase the question to be less argumentative, because I think the question is worth discussing.

Comment: It is true. Javadoc is stuck in the 1990s. Not an answer, but I asked something similar a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382114/javafx-and-javadoc

Comment: It is not and was not phrased arrogantly and aggressively, just not politically correct enough. Writing HTML in Java was a cool idea 20 years ago, but now it feels just terrible, when compared to [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1043720/581205).

Comment: Too bad none of these great answers was accepted... *hint hint*

Answer (score 44):

I have created a [Markdown (java) Doclet](http://code.google.com/p/markdown-doclet/) which will take source comments in Markdown formatted text and create the same HTML Javadocs.

The new doclet also does some restyling on the text, but the HTML generated is not changed at this stage.

That goes some way to address the HTML-in-java-commenting issues which is probably the biggest usability problem with current Javadoc.

Answer (score 21):

I don't think that the concepts of Javadoc are outdated. As far as i can see, these concepts are rooted years ago in a product named doxygen, which is still available for other languages (i.e. Objective-C where it is heavily used). Even this has it's predecessors - have a look at the programming environment used by Donald Knuth to create TeX ([Literate programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming)).

Nevertheless it is a intriguing idea to have a single source for program code and documentation.

Besides of that, the presentation of the documentation can be customized to your special needs using a plug-in system supported by the JavaDoc tool. You might provide a plug-in (as we do) that publishes directly into a database which is directly accessible via web. Using collaborations anyone can provide additional comments or clarifications to the documentation that might find their way back into the original source.

Comment: Please have a look at ScalaDoc2 http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/ and then say again Javadoc is not outdated. :-)  Although I do admit that's more or less the same basic concepts, just a WAY better implementation. One could probably do the same with a new implementation of the javadoc tool.

Answer (score 13):

Javadoc is the best source code auto-documentation generation system I've ever seen. Large part of that is that it's so simple - I can browse javadocs even with my 5 year old cell phone if I want to! While I agree that a bit of a facelift could be in order and especially JDK is a pain to browse through, I wouldn't dare reinventing the wheel entirely because what we currently have is a RESTful, easy to use solution for its purpose which works just about anywhere.

Comment: Well, with the problem that the intra-page links (e.g. `http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])`) are invalid since they use parentheses, brackets and other characters that aren't allowed. This causes them to break in some browsers.

Comment: BTW, an update to this comment, I actually do think nowadays that scaladoc2 (see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html) is actually better than javadoc, although mostly because it borrows the good parts from javadocs and then adds some other nifty things in there.

Comment: Yet another update, javadoc system got an overhaul in JDK7 and looks rather spiffy nowadays, for reference check the official API javadoc at http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Yes but it is SO UGLY!

Comment: @Ziggy Make your own CSS then or use the aforementioned API to generate a completely unique doc page? :P

Comment: @Esko I know, I know. Still though, you have to admit: other things are getting prettier. Ruby updates their doc styles...

Comment: Well, so did Sun/Oracle with the release of Java 7. Scala's docs are actually good example of pretty but horrible to use, despite looking simple you need to learn a lot of magical behavior about it. Looks != Usability

Answer (score 11):

I recently got a mail forwarded that Sun is working on modernizing the Javadoc HTML output. From said mail:

> We are proposing improvements to javadoc/doclet for JDK7. The 
>   project wiki page is located at 
>   http://wikis.sun.com/display/Javadoc/Home. As a part of the proposed 
>   improvements, the UI of the javadoc output will be revamped. The new 
>   design screenshots are uploaded to the project wiki. The javadoc output 
>   markup will be modified to be valid HTML and WCAG 2.0 compliant.

So there is definitely still work going on there, even if somewhat late. However, in my eyes one of the biggest drawbacks of Javadoc is its very close coupling with HTML. Many classes have Javadoc which includes literal HTML and relies on the output being HTML, too. Unfortunate, but this won't change anytime, I think. Still, this means that developers are free to include whatever they want in HTML there which might as well be invalid, non-well-formed, etc. So adapting the output from the javadoc tool is only one part of this, the other won't and can't change and thus remains.

As for browsing documentation I also find the HTML documentation a little unwieldy. I usually use the Javadoc view in Eclipse. It has drawbacks as well (slow and you can't really search) but it's Good Enough™ for most things.

Comment: GREAT NEWS !!! THANK YOU !!! I will now edit my question to provide this useful link.

Comment: @ivan_ivanovich_ivanoff, perhaps you could voice your concerns with the Sun team too.  Sounds like if they can make you happy, it will benefit the all of us.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I still find Javadoc to be very useful. Especially since it is standardized. I don't know of any major documentation style that I find easier to navigate (that might very well be subjective, but I personally find MSDN horrible to use, for example).

For the search: Use the [Javadoc Search Frame](http://code.google.com/p/javadoc-search-frame/), it makes using Javadoc of all kinds a lot easier. It's available as a [Userscript for Firefox](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/23200) and as a [Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mfgkihmpcjjnijmkchojlbccbmhcdfcd).

Comment: It looks to me like Javadoc Search Frame only searches on package and class names in the left hand frame, which is useful, but not as useful as a full text search would be.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your Practical Question, I googled and asked friends and came up with these. Forrestdoc,doclet and doxygen.

The second question, I would say that yes, its not very "Web-oh-twoeye" but At least your guaranteed to work in an offline environment, and its small enough to ship along with your API. i dispise the use of frames, but then it works rather well for javadoc. I have not seen any plans to change it. 
Eclipse has some support for javadoc as far as reading, interpreting and generating it goes.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to phrase that in a less agressive and overbearing manner. Most people don't care what a technical resource looks like, and "It's not Web 2.0 enough!" sounds like vapid marketroidspeak.

And what exactly would you consider "more usable"? Personally, I would definitely like a full text search and a better useage browser, and AJAX could probable help with those.

Well, the nice thing about JavaDoc is that it's the opposite of outdated - it's arbitrarily extensible. Why don't you go ahead and write a [doclet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html) that produces the kind of API doc you want?

Why nobody else has done that so far (which apparently is the case) is anyone's guess - maybe nobody else feels as strongly about it as you.

Comment: 1) It is a fact that people's impression of usability depends on good design. 2) AJAX - for a local file:// resource? 3) I'm sure, nobody in the C/C++ ecosystem feels as strongly about consistent naming as I do, but this does not invalidates the needs for consistent naming.

Comment: 1) What exactly would you consider "good design" then? I, for one, think that the regular JavaDoc is well-designed. 2) Would not be real AJAX, I suppose, but similar functionality should actually be possible. 3) Still, it looks like the current JavaDoc is good enough for most people that nobody has bothered making a better one so far - which would be not all that difficult.

Comment: 1) Standard part: strongly structured data, not HTML. Implementation part: a desktop app written in Java ;) 3) I think many volunteers could be found to improve Javadoc, but to make it serious a JSR would be needed. Not realistic to achieve for this topic.

Comment: @ivan_ivanovich_ivanoff: What do you think which strongly structured data is needed? And why not writing a javadoc-doclet, that produces this format? And I absolotely oppose the idea of a desktop-app, because it locks you on the specific app to view the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There's a DocBook doclet. DocBook is a richer document type than (X)HTML and is better for describing  technical content. From DocBook source you can generate all sorts of different output formats.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would like a more readable "comment documentation" standard than the HTML (and hence tag-wieldy) JavaDoc.

For example, MarkDown, as used here, would be excellent, human readable in the source, nicely formatted external to the source.

With the current JavaDoc, I imagine many people use JavaDoc comments, but don't actually document to the extent they could. I'm sure everyone has browsed an API's online JavaDoc that has been non-documented or barely-documented, and thus far harder to use than it should be.

This isn't helped by code-reformatters (e.g., within Eclipse, or maybe upon source commit) that totally destroy any readable structure you might have put within a JavaDoc comment (e.g., a list of items) into one big blob of text, unless you literally use two carriage returns where you wish to use one).

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know, if there some plans to evolve Javadoc, in a somehow-standardized way?

The corresponding JSR (JSR 260), which specifies enhancements to Javadoc, has been voted out of JDK 7 (for now). An overview of what was planned (from [this site](https://javadoctags.dev.java.net/)):

> Upgrade Javadoc to provide a richer set of tags to allow more structured presentation of Javadoc documentation. This JSR covers: categorization of methods and fields, semantical index of classes and packages, distinction of static, factory, deprecated methods from ordinary methods, distinction of property accessors, combining and splitting information into views, embedding of examples and common use-cases, and more.

The overall outlook for JDK 7 is [pretty grim](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/).

Answer (score 1):

JavaDoc is itself extremely flexible because you can replace the standard doclet with a custom doclet to provide something that meets your projects specific needs.

On the project I've been working on, we created an HTML/XML-based documentation system (using client-side XSLT 2.0 on JS) for our product with JavaDoc fully integrated. For this, a custom doclet was used to produce JavaDoc data in XML, this used tagsoup to ensure even HTML markup within code comments were well formed.

With this, we were able to deliver an interactive user experience using a single-page app (similar to a desktop tool), but all from within the browser - without any server-side code/infrastructure. The viewer included standard features such as search, tree navigation etc.

Here's a link to a sample entry point in the rather vast documentation:
[JavaDoc viewer sample](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon.om/FunctionItem)

Here's an image also:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**A smart seachable javadoc viewer:**

For many times, I face the problem of browsing JavaDoc. I was looking for something just like Adnroid doc search option. At last I get something like that. If you use firefox the solution is here.

1. Install the plugin GreaseMonkey, its kinda customizing web page the way we see. ( We need to customize any java doc page, so we can search on class name)
    https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/
2. For greasemonkey to work, we need some user script for customization. This can be downloaded by greasemonkey automatically. Install the userscript from [JavaDoc search frame](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/23200) or [JavaDoc incremental search](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/1428).

This works great for me.