# Stackoverflow markup for javadoc

Tags: javadoc, markdown, markup

After a while, I'm back writing JavaDoc. At the same time I grew fond of SO's markup, which is way more readable in plaintext than HTML. (Even the *back tick* which I never used before, ever).

```
/**
 * I'm talking about things like <code>ClassName</code> here.
 * <p>
 * And of course the well-known <code>&lt;p&gt;</code>.<br>
 * Should I go on?
 */
```

Has anyone written some filter thingy which translates SO markup to HTML in the JavaDoc tool chain?

Alternatively **as comments** any pointers would be welcome how to write extensions to JavaDoc with such functionality (I'm mainly interested in the interface if there is any available).

Comment: While I can certainly see the appeal of having this, I'd be careful: many, many tools assume that JavaDoc comments contain HTML and that assumption might be tricky to turn off. For example, by default Eclipse formats JavaDoc comments by removing unimportant whitespace (for HTML). This would ruin markup.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There appears to be a [Markdown Doclet](https://github.com/Abnaxos/markdown-doclet) for Javadoc, which should do what you want.

It's made by StackOverflow-user [Richard Nichols](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71159/richard-nichols). He has written [a blog post](http://www.richardnichols.net/2009/06/markdown-doclet-for-javadoc/) on it, which includes a screenshot, of some example input/output.

Comment: The link to the original answer from Richard, if someone wants to vote it up, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026553/are-there-some-good-and-modern-alternatives-to-javadoc/1043720#1043720

Comment: It seems the project has gone a bit stale :/

Comment: Unfortunately, the first link is now broken, as is every link pointing to Google Code.

Answer (score 17):

MarkdownDoclet is a bit outdated.

For Java 7, use https://github.com/Abnaxos/pegdown-doclet

Comment: It seems the project has gone a bit stale :/

Comment: Activity on this project has picked back up.